# How to send SMS 5 days before the date with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, sms

After the Excel output, I want to send an SMS to the person's mobile number with the date entered in Excel 5 days before that date.

I also used the job command.

Controller.php

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new OtherImport, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));
    $insuranceData = Other::query()->select('personal_insurance', 'mobile')->get();

    $sentMobileNumbers = [];

    foreach ($insuranceData as $data) {
        $insuranceDate = $data->personal_insurance;
        $mobileNumber = $data->mobile;

        if (!empty($insuranceDate) && !in_array($mobileNumber, $sentMobileNumbers)) {
            try {
                $jalaliDate = Jalalian::fromFormat('Y/m/d', $insuranceDate);
                $carbonDate = Carbon::create($jalaliDate->getYear(), $jalaliDate->getMonth(), $jalaliDate->getDay());
                $smsDate = $carbonDate->subDay(5); 

                if ($smsDate->isPast()) {
                    SendSmsJob::dispatch([$mobileNumber]); 
                    $sentMobileNumbers[] = $mobileNumber; 
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                dd($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use

```
dispatch()->delay(now()->addDays(5));
```

Bur remember that you need to do some changes

1. Change QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync in your ENV file. You have to use a driver that allows you to use the queue, for example 'database'
2. Then enable the queue worker  with php artisan queue:work or supervisor if you're in production.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to send a [job with a delay](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) to the queue. Then use the `smsDate` variable. I would suggest also setting a time to trigger the sending of the sms at a convenient time for the customer.